# Is it possible to use styles in an external assembly without merging them into the ResourceDictionary of app.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The desired scenario I'm trying to address goes like this:

1. there is a set of common styles defined in the MyCompany.Styles.dll assembly.
2. there is a set of custom controls in the MyCompany.Controls.dll assembly that use the styles in the MyCompany.Styles.dll assembly.
3. any application that uses the controls in the MyCompany.Controls.dll assembly will not need to reference any ResourceDictionary in the MyCompany.Styles.dll assembly in the application's app.xaml, but the styles will just resolve given the fact that they are referenced and used by the MyCompany.Controls.dll assembly.

Is this possible to do and if so, how?

Thanks much,  eugen

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, so I'm posting the solution for anyone who stumbles upon my original question.

The fix is to merge the desired styles into the ResourceDictionary of each of the custom controls in the MyCompany.Controls.dll assembly.  While I weren't successful doing this in XAML, all it took was to add the call below into each custom control's constructor:

```
this.MergeInResources("/MyCompany.Styles;component/default.xaml");
```

where the extension method that does the magic is below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the resources pointed to by the (relative) path
    /// <paramref name="resourcePath"/> into the Merged Dictionaries
    /// of <paramref name="control"/>.
    /// </summary>
    internal static void MergeInResources(this FrameworkElement control,
                                          string resourcePath)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resourcePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("resourcePath");

        Uri uri = new Uri(resourcePath, UriKind.Relative);
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
        control.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
    }
```

Error handling and ResourceDictionary caching + sharing is left to the reader.